# How to use Google Activity Result API in One Tap sign-in

Tags: android, google-api, android-signing, google-one-tap

In one of my Android applications I am trying to include One Tap sign-in authentication by following the example https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap. However, here https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,int) it says that the function startActivityForResult is deprecated and to use instead the function registerForActivityResult passing in a StartActivityForResult object for the ActivityResultContract. With the help of other examples, I could write the following code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SignInClient oneTapClient;
    private BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> loginResultHandler = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
        // handle intent result here
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            SignInCredential credential = null;
            try {
                credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                String username = credential.getId();
                String password = credential.getPassword();
                if (idToken != null) {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.");
                } else if (password != null) {
                    // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got password.");
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //...
        }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                       /*try {
                           android.app.Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender(), REQ_ONE_TAP,
                                    null, 0, 0, 0);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }*/
                        loginResultHandler.launch(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender());
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                        // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

only I can't figure out how to convert the instruction loginResultHandler.launch(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()) according to the Google Activity Result API (getIntentSender() returns an
IntentSender but loginResultHandler.launch() requires an
Intent). Would anyone be able to help me or link me working examples? Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Finally, I rewrote the code in the following way (I have tested it up to the account selection screen and it works):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private SignInClient oneTapClient;
    private BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;
    private boolean showOneTapUI = true;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> loginResultHandler = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), result -> {
        // handle intent result here
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_OK.");
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CANCELED) Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED.");
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_FIRST_USER) Log.d(TAG, "RESULT_FIRST_USER.");
            try {
                SignInCredential credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                String username = credential.getId();
                String password = credential.getPassword();
                if (idToken !=  null) {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.");
                } else if (password != null) {
                    // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got password.");
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                switch (e.getStatusCode()) {
                    case CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "One-tap dialog was closed.");
                        // Don't re-prompt the user.
                        showOneTapUI = false;
                        break;
                    case CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR:
                        Log.d(TAG, "One-tap encountered a network error.");
                        // Try again or just ignore.
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get credential from result."
                                + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        break;
                }
            }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                        try {
                            loginResultHandler.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build());
                        } catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                        // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult` class instead of the `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult`

And therefore you can refactor your code to something like this,

First define what will be done when the result is given to you using the `ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest>` instance rather than the `ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>` instance

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> loginResultHandler = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), result -> {
        // handle intent result here
        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
            SignInCredential credential = null;
            try {
                credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                String username = credential.getId();
                String password = credential.getPassword();
                if (idToken != null) {
                    // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.");
                } else if (password != null) {
                    // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                    // with your backend.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Got password.");
                }
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            //...
        }
    });
```

And now in your `onCreate` as you mentioned above in your code, you can use `IntentSenderRequest.Builder` class to turn your `IntentSender` instance into a `IntentSenderRequest` instance which will be accepted in the `launch` method

```
oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInRequest)
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                     

                        try{
                            loginResultHandler.launch(new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build());
                           }catch(IntentSenderException e){
                              e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                        // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Make sure you wrap that in a `try-catch` construct and it should be it.

Just came across this [answer](https://proandroiddev.com/phone-selector-api-with-activityresultcontracts-in-kotlin-2cbc39252b42) while googling, it might help you too

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71807201/what-is-sign-up-in-one-tap-used-for-on-android)?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer, here is a similar solution written in Kotlin:

Initiate sign-in flow from onCreate() method

```
signInClient.beginSignIn(buildSignInRequest())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
            try {
                signInResultHandler.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.pendingIntent.intentSender).build())
            } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
            // TODO - No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI
            Log.d(TAG, "No saved credentials found: ${e.message}")
        }
```

And handle sign-in result

```
private val signInResultHandler = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { activityResult: ActivityResult ->
    when (activityResult.resultCode) {
        RESULT_OK -> {
            try {
                val idToken = signInClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(activityResult.data).googleIdToken
                when {
                    idToken != null -> {
                        // TODO - Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate with Firebase
                        Log.d(TAG, "Got ID token.")
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No ID token!") // Shouldn't happen
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                when (e.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "One-tap dialog was closed.")
                        showOneTapUI = false // Don't re-prompt the user
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "One-tap encountered a network error.")
                        // TODO - Try again or just ignore
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get credential from result: ${e.message}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```