# What is sign-up in One Tap used for on Android?

Tags: android, google-signin, google-one-tap

I'm trying to implement [One Tap sign-in and sign-up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-started) in my project. I have created a brand new emulator but I didn't sing in with a Google account. When I try to **sign-up** in my app, I was expecting to redirect me to a screen where I should provide my Google credentials, but I get an error saying:

```
Cannot find a matching credential.
```

So I need to first sign in in my emulator and then sign-up in my app? If so, then what is the sign-up good for?

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help.

Answer (score -1):

**I have a solution for this Please use web App Clint key**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: At the time, there was an issue where the Web Client ID and Android Client ID seemingly swapped places. But that's been fixed now, so continue to use the Android Client ID.